# Prevent duplicate registrations - Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, duplicates, castle-windsor, ioc-container

sorry if this has been asked before i've tried doing some google-ing and haven't found any matches so here goes....

I have a Castle Windsor container that I add my components to using the following method (where container is an instance of `IWindsorContainer`)...

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("App.Infrastructure")
    .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
```

This works great, however I then want to register another DLL in the same fashion to resolve dependencies from that...

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("App.Client.Infrastructure")
    .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
```

Now is there anyway I can get Windsor to notify me if the same interface resolution is being added, ie: only have 1 implementer per interface (take the first if more than one exists).

Hope I have explained myself well enough. I am using Castle Windsor version: 2.5.1.0 and upgrading / changing version is not really an options.

---

Update:

I've resolved this by removing the duplicate registrations after they have been registered.
After the registration is completed I then have a loop below...

```
var registeredServices = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
foreach (var node in container.Kernel.GraphNodes)
{
    var cmp = ((Castle.Core.ComponentModel)node);
    Type t = cmp.Service;
    if (registeredServices.ContainsKey(t))
        container.Kernel.RemoveComponent(cmp.Name);
    else
        registeredServices.Add(t, cmp.Implementation.FullName);
}
```

Comment: it should be default behavior that first registration is resolved

Comment: Hi @maxlego. I don't understand what you mean, could you please elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: if you register multiple components with the same interface. then when you resolve by this interface you'll get first registered component. As i understand this is what you want. Or is it not?

Comment: Thanks @maxlego, I want it to throw an exception or something similar as we only want one registered component per interface, sorry if I haven't made that clear in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i don't know if you can tweak registrars to throw exception, but this simple code snippet might help you

```
var registeredServices = new List<Type>();

foreach (var node in container.Kernel.GraphNodes)
{
    foreach (var t in ((Castle.Core.ComponentModel)node).Services)
    {
        if (registeredServices.Contains(t))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("service {0} already registered", t));
        registeredServices.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2.5 you can, after registering everything, call

```
var allHandlers = container.Kernel.GetAssingableHandlers(typeof(object));
```

then you can look at each handler's `.Service` and find if there are any duplicates, and either throw a helpful exception or something along those lines.

I'd imagine this is something you want to do in a test, not at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, This is exactly the position I am trying to perform the check in. We've got a unit test looking for duplicate registrations that is failing and I was hoping for a way to detect what is being duplicated. Thanks guys will try both your solutions and report back my findings!